# containsPoint: for UIBezierPath crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-core

I'm parsing a SVG file to `UIBezierPath`. I'd like to know whether a `CGPoint` is inside or outside the `UIBezierPath`. To do this I use `containsPoint:`. When I run this in the simulator everthing works fine (almost!). When I run it a iPad device it crashes on some paths and points. I'm calling `closePath` on every `UIBezierPath` before I call `containsPoint:`.

Here are some paths and points, which makes it crash (I randomize the points, so there might be more crash points):

```
Crash Points: (659.0, 444.0), (659.0, 443.0)
SVG Path: M661 446 c1 -1 3 -1 4 -1 1 -1 2 -2 2 -4 0 -2 0 -2 -2 -2 0 1 -2 1 -3 1 -2 0 -3 1 -3 2 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 0 1 1 2 1z

Crash Points: (533.0, 458.0), (533.0, 457.0)
SVG Path: M535 460 c0 0 1 -1 1 -2 1 -2 0 -3 -1 -3 0 0 -1 0 -2 1 0 1 0 2 0 3 1 0 1 1 2 1z
```

I can't figure out why it crashes. To me it should return `YES` or `NO` no matter what path or point it gets.

Why does it crash? :-(

Comment: please post the code where you call `containsPoint:`

Comment: i can reproduce your crashes on the device (maybe you should file a bugreport to apple). Very strange. If Performance/precision is not that crucial in your case, you could rasterize the path and do a simple color-lookup for testing.

Comment: I experience the same behavior: Works on simulator, crashes on device. Looks like a genuine bug worthy of [https://bugreport.apple.com/](https://bugreport.apple.com/). By the way, you'll have to provide them more information than above, e.g. show them the actual path you generated rather than the SVG string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the crash is a bug in the framework. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536912/1118969) provides another way to determine whether a point is inside a `UIBezierPath`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the hit testing techniques in this post:

http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/

I've use this in one of my apps and it works without any problems. His examples were all I needed to get things working. If you need more help I can post some of my code tonight.

If you need any help with the SVG parsing, I forked a github project to do parsing of SVG paths, and extended it to support line and polyline elements. I'm converting SVGs to UIBezierPaths and then doing animation and hit testing for finger drawing.

https://github.com/stevekohls/PocketSVG